# To use or not to use -fpic

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-optimization, fpic

My application needs to load one or more algorithms at run time and I use .so for this. The thing is that these libraries are not used by any other process but my applicaiton so there is no need to share the .text section with others. Some parts of the .so come from other static libraries that I compile beforehand.

In this case, do I still have to use -fpic flag for the static files?

**EDIT**

I found this article [article](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~gbournou/CSE131/the_inside_story_on_shared_libraries_and_dynamic_loading.pdf). At page 7 it states this "So, if performance is important for a library or dynamically loadable module, you can compile it as non-PIC code. The primary downside to compiling the module as non-PIC is that loading time in-creases because the dynamic linker must make a large number of code patches when binding symbols."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you do.  Anything that will be loaded with `dlopen` must be compiled using `-fpic` (or `-fPIC`).

This is not about sharing the text segment, but about the different rules for accessing global data (including things that you might not realize *are* global data, such as the "procedure linkage table" trampolines used to call between global functions) in the main executable versus in shared libraries.

Comment: I found this article https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~gbournou/CSE131/the_inside_story_on_shared_libraries_and_dynamic_loading.pdf . At page 7 it states this "So, if performance is important for a library or dynamically loadable module, you can compile it as non-PIC code. The primary downside to compiling the module as non-PIC is that loading time in-creases because the dynamic linker must make a large number of code patches when binding symbols."

Comment: I don't mind the extra loading time but I would mind if -fpic adds some performance overhead during run time of the algortihm.

Comment: @user1934513 That article is very old and what it says was only ever true for 32-bit x86 with Linux.  With any other combination of CPU and operating system, compiling shared objects as PIC is mandatory.